# Bind Array Item to [(value)] in Angular

Tags: angular, material-ui

Hi i am working with Angular material and i have an Array of products that creates a table in my template

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of productArray | async; let i = index">
```

Inside this loop i have another loop on a `<th>` tag:

```
<th>
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Length" formControlName="lengthOption" [compareWith]="compareWith" [(value)]="item.lengthOption">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let lengthOption of item.lengthOptions" [value]="lengthOption">
              {{lengthOption.name}}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

I would like to make use of the two way binding of `[(value)]`.

I know i can set `[value]` to be lengthOption.name for example and then set the binding to `[(Value)]="selected"` and then i can set this in my component `(selected = whatever)` or view it in the template via `{{selected}}`.

My query is can i get this value from the parent array like i am trying in the inner loop:

```
*ngFor="let item of productArray | async; let i = index"

[(value)]="item.lengthOption"
```

lengthOption does exist on productArray.

The point of this i want to set a initial selected value for each products mat-select.

lengthOption looks like `{ "id": 1, "name": "Ten Years" }`

So i am trying to set the object to the mat-option from a parent array, not just a object value form its own array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put your all ts and html file code so It can be more helpful to understand issue.

Comment: Some like productArray.forEach(item=>{item.lengthOption=item.lengthOptions[0]})?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a new property to item (the selected one) and change it on ngModelChange

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Length" formControlName="lengthOption" (ngModelChange)="select($event, item)" [compareWith]="compareWith" [(value)]="item.lengthOption">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let lengthOption of item.lengthOptions" [value]="lengthOption">
        ...
```

and try something like this to change each time you select a new one :

```
select(selectedValue, item) {
 item['selectedLengthOption'] = selectedValue;
}
```

and you can access it in your template inside your loop

```
{{item.selectedLengthOption}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Two way binding is not suggested with dynamic name and it doesn't work in expected way.
Treat this [(value)] as [(ngModel)]

You may use (onChange) or if you want to do need to get all form status/info and if your product array has more item, try using formArray it will make your life easy.
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray